# Best Practices for sharing code repo between environments?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-data-factory

I have Data Factories within 3 different environments - Production, Test and Development.

Behind the scenes, we have an Azure DevOps Code Repo which is currently connected to the Prod environment, and we are using branches and PRs to publish changes.  This works well.

I want to link the Code Repo to both Dev and Test environments, so Dev has a main branch of "Dev", Test has a main branch of "Test", and all three environments share the same Code Repo.

I have created a Dev branch, and a Test branch, for collaboration purposes.  However, I'm not sure what to do with the publish branches.  Do I have the ability to disable publishing from DEV and Test environments?  Do I leave as adf_publish or should the publish branch be something else, eg "adf_publish_dev", "adf_publish_test", etc?

I'm still new to Code Repos etc.  Switching to GIT is not an option.  Have googled but find some relevant articles but nothing that mirrors exactly what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create any new branch as the same `adf_publish` branch can be used to deploy Dev, Test and Prod environment. You just need to create a separate DevOps pipeline for each environment. In the same ARM template you can override the parameters for different environment.

In Azure DevOps portal, follow: **Pipeline -> `Use the classic editor` to create pipeline without YAML -> Azure Repos Git**.

Under **Default branch for manual and schedule builds** option use **`adf_publish`** branch.

In next step click on `Empty job`

Click on `+` symbol on `Agent job 1` option and search for `ARM template deployed` and configure the arm deployment setting. Here you can use all the existing ARM templates from existing environment and Override the parameters under `Override template parameters` option.

This way you can use same code for different environment.